# Tailwind - dynamic number of columns to cater for an unknown number of items

Tags: tailwind-css

I suspect the answer to this will be a resounding no, but here's hoping.

I have a number of items to display in a 3 column grid (on larger widths - at smaller widths they just display one above the other).

Can I use any aspect of Tailwind to make it so that they display nicely no matter if the number of items is divisible by 3 (without remainder) or not?

As things stand, if there are 7 items, the 7th item displays in the left-most column. Ideally it would display in the middle column. Likewise, if there are 8 items, the 7th and 8th display in the left-most and middle columns respectively, whereas ideally they would be centered so that the 7th sits evenly under the 4th and 5th, and the 8th sits evenly under the 5th and 6th.

I suspect that it will have to fall back on some PHP to calculate the layout of the last row depending on the remainder (if any) from X / 3, but live in hope.

Comment: The layout you're describing may be one that you think is needed but people are very accustomed to the left to right placement which is the default of grid. Instagram, among many others, deal with grids using default placement on hanging items. Perhaps you're creating a problem for yourself which won't actually benefit your users or your application.

Comment: @JHeth but I want it to look pretty, though. And the hanging items don't look pretty to me. ;-)

Comment: A perfectly understandable bias to have, personally when I see the centered hanging columns on a design it looks off to me which distracts from the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to achieve such grid structure is to use [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) layout. In Tailwind 3-column [grid](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns#specifying-the-columns-in-a-grid) can be made simply by `grid grid-cols-3`. Every new row will be filling in from left to right. If you need to add gap between elements use `gap-{n}` [utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap). This way no math required

```html
<ul class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
  <li class="">1</li>
  <li class="">2</li>

  // and so on...
  <li class="">8</li>
</ul>
```

Alomost identical result can be achieved via `columns-{n}` [utilitiy](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/columns#adding-based-on-column-count)

```html
<ul class="columns-3 gap-6">
  <li class="mb-6">1</li>
  <li class="mb-6">2</li>
  // ...
  <li class="mb-6">8</li>
</ul>
```

However if you wish your elements to be centered there you should do some calculations

1st way - using grid - is to double the amount of columns (as centered element may be placed in between two elements) and define starting position of the FIRST element of the LAST row depends based on result of division for `amount of elements / 3`. If `1 === N % 3` - it should be `col-start-3`, `2 === N % 3` - `col-start-2` and no extra class needed for `0 === N % 3`

As now we have 6 columns but want to show only 3, every element need to be stretched on two columns via `col-span-2`

```html
<ul class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
  <li class="col-span-2">1</li>
  <li class="col-span-2">2</li>
  // ...
  <li class="col-span-2">6</li>
  <li class="col-start-2 col-span-2">7</li>
  <li class="col-span-2">8</li>
</ul>

<ul class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6 bg-slate-50 p-6">
  <li class="col-span-2">1</li>
  <li class="col-span-2">2</li>
  // ...
  <li class="col-span-2">6</li>
  <li class="col-span-2 col-start-3">7</li>
</ul>
```

There is also a flex way but is requires more calculations. Every element within should be stretched on one third (33%) of its parent. But the gap between them is not counted so you'll see two elements in a row - that's we have to substract these gaps from every element. There are two gaps between three elements - `gap-6` class actually generates `1.5rem` - so `1.5 * 2 / 3 = 1rem`

```html
<ul class="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-6">
  <li class="w-[calc(33.333%-1rem)]">1</li>
  <li class="w-[calc(33.333%-1rem)]">2</li>
  // ...
  <li class="w-[calc(33.333%-1rem)]">8</li>
</ul>
```

Note: all provided examples are for non-responsive design. Use Tailwind [breakpoints](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) for this. But my point is you have to make such calculations for centered elements whenever your design "breaks" - if you have two elements in a row you will need another values for element width or starting column position

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/1BRoFK10Mj)

Comment: Great, thank you - I shall play around with those ideas.